# typealias for global kotlinx.serialization not work

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

First I'll post the code

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializer(forClass = UUID::class)
object UUIDserializer : KSerializer<UUID> {
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): UUID = UUID.fromString(decoder.decodeString())

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
        get() = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("UUID", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: UUID) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
    }
}
typealias SID = @Serializable(with = UUIDserializer::class) UUID
fun randomSid() = UUID.randomUUID() as SID
@Serializable
data class Example(val id:SID = randomSid())
class SerializeId {
    @Test
    fun nestedTypeUsage() {
        val example = Example()
        val string = Json.encodeToString(example)
        println(string)
    }
    @Test
    fun directTypeUsage () {
        val hi = randomSid()
        val string = Json.encodeToString(hi)
        println(string)
    }
}
```

nestedTypeUsage run and passes, but directTypeUsage fails.

> Serializer for class 'UUID' is not found.
> Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
> kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'UUID' is not found

I can't apply the @Serializable annotation directly to a val or a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost immediately after posting this. I realized I can

```
@Test
fun directTypeUsage () {
    val hi = randomSid()
    val string = hi.toString()
    println(string)
}
```